# Knockoutjs foreach with if inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a foreach creating a table in one of my pages. My goal is when they checked the checkbox I would show additional elements for that table

My issue is when the table is first drawn everything works as expected. But if i check a checkbox after the table is drawn the ko if statement does not reevaluate. What is the best method to accomplish this goal? My current code is below.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: AvailableCerts">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="label-checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: Id, checked: IsSelected">
                <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
                <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
            </label>

        </td>
        <td data-bind="text:CertifyingBody"></td>
        <td>
            <!-- ko if: (IsSelected) -->
            <input data-bind="value : EntryDate" required type="date" class="form-control input-sm">
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- ko if: ExitDateRequired -->
            <input data-bind="value : ExitDate" required type="date" class="form-control input-sm">
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- ko if: CaseNumberRequired -->
            <input data-bind="value : CaseNumber" required type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And my viewModel

```
 function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.rootUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/Certs/";
    self.AvailableCerts = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.getAvailableCerts = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: self.rootUrl + "AvailableCerts",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (results) {
                if (results != null) {
                    self.AvailableCerts(results);
                } else {
                    self.AvailableCerts([]);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    self.getAvailableCerts();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the ko.observableArray AvailableCerts are not observable by default. If you plan on working with the data after downloading it, you need to make the data for each of the certs observable as well. So, something like this in your Ajax call:

```
self.getAvailableCerts = function () {
  $.ajax({
      url: self.rootUrl + "AvailableCerts",
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (results) {
          if (results != null) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                self.AvailableCerts().push({
                    'IsSelected': ko.observable(results[i].IsSelected),
                    'ExitDateRequired': ko.observable(results[i].ExitDateRequired),
                    'CaseNumberRequired': ko.observable(results[i].CaseNumberRequired)
                });
              }
          } else {
              self.AvailableCerts([]);
          }
      }
  });
};
```

Or checkout the [mappings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.